# Repair root following "rm -r ~" error

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, root, home-directory, rm

I was running a terminal as root and following installing a package noticed I had created a new directory in error.

I used `rm -r` and began typing the directory when my cat jumped up onto my desk.

I got as far as `rm -r ~` before it stepped onto my keyboard and pressed enter.

Now I so far... nothing seems to have broken except for being unable to run `cd` without any path specification as root.
All other users still work.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (Xubuntu)

How can I repair root and can I find out what was removed with `rm`?

I am painfully aware that I've probably made many a bad practice, and I beg you forgiveness!!

Edit:

So far the only error I have come across is running `nautilus` as root which prints the following into the terminal:

```
(nautilus:26195): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:157: Unable to connect to session bus: The connection is closed

(nautilus:26195): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:157: Unable to connect to session bus: The connection is closed

(nautilus:26195): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:157: Unable to connect to session bus: The connection is closed
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Error creating proxy: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)

(nautilus:26195): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(nautilus:26195): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(nautilus:26195): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_call_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

Comment: Cats and root in the same room is always a matter of when --not if-- the disaster will occur.

Comment: ... and `rm -r` as root should not be a command to run when cats are near ;-).

Comment: I have seen enough cat videos to know that *the cat knows*.

Comment: Good reminder to use `sudo` instead of running terminal as root. If you know you're going to type a command whose early completion would be catastrophic, it's best to also do so from a new session (so you will be prompted for a password)

Answer (score 2):

If you had no custom environment variables or scripts that you want run on login, it might be as easy as `mkdir /root`

If you did have custom scripts, you'll have to recreate them after you do this.

If you log in remotely as root (very much not recommended), you will need to recreate your `~/.ssh` folder, and create an `authorized_keys` file. Don't forget to add the `ssh` keys in there of any hosts you log in from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not have any custom scripts or variables set.
I run everything as separate users and they seem to be completely unaffected .
I misspoke when I said logged in as root, I ```su root``` in a terminal while logged in as another user. 
Just attempted to run nautilus in the root terminal and this gave an error.

Comment: There were likely also default `.profile` and `.bashrc` files in `/root`, that may be re-copied from the `/etc/skel` directory